# jenkins installation in Solaris server

Tags: jenkins, solaris

How to install the jenkins on a solaris server? i found articles that this cannot be done as jenkins has discontinued support for solaris.

Answer (score 2):

Even though official IPS repositories for Solaris are discontinued, you can still run Jenkins in Solaris via the jenkins webapp (jenkins.war). To quote from [Jenkins installation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#solaris-omnios-smartos-and-other-siblings) doc:

> **Solaris, OmniOS, SmartOS, and other siblings**
>
> Generally it should
>   suffice to install Java 8 and download the jenkins.war and run it as a
>   standalone process or under an application server such as Apache
>   Tomcat.
>
> Some caveats apply:
>
> - Headless JVM and fonts: For OpenJDK builds on minimalized-footprint
>     systems, there may be issues running the headless JVM, because Jenkins
>     needs some fonts to render certain pages.
> - ZFS-related JVM crashes: When Jenkins runs on a system detected as a
>     SunOS, it tries to load integration for advanced ZFS features using
>     the bundled libzfs.jar which maps calls from Java to native libzfs.so
>     routines provided by the host OS. Unfortunately, that library was made
>     for binary utilities built and bundled by the OS along with it at the
>     same time, and was never intended as a stable interface exposed to
>     consumers. As the forks of Solaris legacy, including ZFS and later the
>     OpenZFS initiative evolved, many different binary function signatures
>     were provided by different host operating systems - and when Jenkins
>     libzfs.jar invoked the wrong signature, the whole JVM process crashed.
>     A solution was proposed and integrated in jenkins.war since weekly
>     release 2.55 (and not yet in any LTS to date) which enables the
>     administrator to configure which function signatures should be used
>     for each function known to have different variants, apply it to their
>     application server initialization options and then run and update the
>     generic jenkins.war without further workarounds. See the libzfs4j Git
>     repository for more details, including a script to try and "lock-pick"
>     the configuration needed for your particular distribution (in
>     particular if your kernel updates bring a new incompatible libzfs.so).
>
> Also note that forks of the OpenZFS initiative may provide ZFS on
>   various BSD, Linux, and macOS distributions. Once Jenkins supports
>   detecting ZFS capabilities, rather than relying on the SunOS check,
>   the above caveats for ZFS integration with Jenkins should be
>   considered.

Comment: I have downloaded the generic war jenkins_2156 and places it in my solaris server. Executed the war using java -jar . But localhost:8080 is not coming up.

Comment: What's the java version you are using? Do you see any logs in the console?